# Compare Hex unix epoch timestamp strings in SQL

Tags: python, sql, datetime, timestamp, sql-timestamp

I have a table where I have 2 fields that represent unix epoch timestamp hex example "62508501", "624F645F".
They are strings data type.
I want to be able to compare the 2 timestamps.

Can I straight up compare these string:

ts1_hex_string >  ts1_hex_string

- Would this be an accurate representation of comparing the actual data/time timestamps?
- If not, what is the easiest way to compare in SQL or python?

Comment: You can only compare numbers as strings if they're the same number of digits. For instance, `"60" > "100"` is true.

Comment: The best way is to convert the hex to a number and then compare that. The fact that they represent timestamps is irrelevant, they're just numbers.

Comment: you seem to be dealing with integer seconds since the epoch, so simply `int("62508501", 16) > int("624F645F", 16)` for example should do.